# Align a HTML table Cell to a column

Tags: html, css, css-tables, tabular

I would like to align a table cell to a column where it belongs:

```
_________________________________________
|       |    First Place |  Second Place |
|       |                |               |
_________________________________________
| 09:00 |                | Break fast    |
|       |                | 09:10 : 09:50 |
_________________________________________
```

But what i get is the next:

```
 _________________________________________   

 |       |    First Place |  Second Place |
 |       |                |               |
  _________________________________________
 | 09:00 | Break fast     |               |
 |       | 09:10 : 09:50  |               |
 _________________________________________
```

The html code / css I am using is the next. Any idea how to achieve the above effect by teaking my HTML or CSS is really welcome.

```css
table.dayEvent {
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-collapse: separate;
  display: table;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  width: 570px;
}
table.dayEvent caption {
  color: rgb(46, 63, 153);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
table.dayEvent thead {
  border-color: inherit;
  display: table-header-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
table.dayEvent tr {
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.dayEvent th {
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
table.dayEvent td {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
table.dayEvent td p {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="dayEvent">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th axis="location" id="firstPlace">FirstPlace</th>
      <th axis="location" id="secondPlace">FirstPlace</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th axis="T09:00" rowspan="12">09:00</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="8" headers="secondPlace">
        <p>Breakfast 9:10 - 9:50</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="noDisplay">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It would be great to hear from a CSS solution!

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
<tr><td rowspan="8" headers="secondPlace"><p>Breakfast 9:10 - 9:50</p></td></tr>
```

to this:

```
<tr><td rowspan="8"></td><td rowspan="8" headers="secondPlace"><p>Breakfast 9:10 - 9:50</p></td></tr>
```

Adds an extra `<td>` element to fix the alignment issues. You might want to set `background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);` on the added cell; since there's no content you probably don't want the white background.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are one `td` short! Insert empty `<td></td>` and it solves the problem.

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td rowspan="8" headers="secondPlace"><p>Breakfast 9:10 - 9:50</p></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "noDisplay" class from the 2nd cell

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do it -- the 2nd cell isn't even in the same row as the cell in question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a rowspan on the row above it. Since it looks like you are trying to make a double schedule calendar what it looks like is that you didn't fill in the same amount of time in First Place as you did in Second place (rowspan="8"). Setting noDisplay to .noDisplay {background-color: purple;} and getting rid of the white background on the td really shows what is going on.

On preview: What everyone else said.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert one more column before the content you publishshing and add this code may be work out
`<td rowspan="8" headers="secondPlace"><p>Breakfast <br/>9:10 - 9:50</p></td></tr>`
you can check out the colours with proper css.